EF Core 8 - Union LINQ query method doesn't work against arbitrary data
I am using EF Core 8 with Npgsql, and I have a model class Attempt:
public class Attempt(int Id, string UserId, int score)
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = Id;
    public string UserId { get; set; } = UserId!;
    public int score { get; set; } = score;
}

I am attempting to execute a query where I take an arbitrary attempt, (essentially just data, not specifically an existing row in the database) and Union it with the current values in the table as a basis for other queries, Similar to this SQL expression:
SELECT *
FROM your_table
UNION
SELECT 'My_data', 56, 'Also_My_Data';

My EF Core query is as follows:
Attempt newAttempt = new(7, "Herb", 56);
var attemptsUnionOne = await db.Attempt.Union([newAttempt]).ToListAsync();

However, I instantly get an exception saying:

The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Union(__p_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Does anyone have an idea why Union cannot be translated in my case?

Are you intending that newAttempt to be saved to the database, or do you only want it client-side?

I am intending only that it be added to the query, not save to the database

The use case for me is that I want to get the rank of a certain attempt were it to be in an existing query of attempts (without loading all of the attempts to the server).

It was not possible in any EF versions.

Does anyone have an idea why Union cannot be translated in my case? Because they didn't write code to do it.

Union in yours example is executed on the DB side, so doing it with local that exists in yours app memory, but doesn't exists in the database can be unexpected thing for EF/Npgsql driver creators. It is better to do that on yours app side, what you can achieve using one of mentioned methods before the Union method.

this answer really helped me understand, I ended up fixing it by doing db.attempts.Union(db.Attempts.Where(at => at.Id == attempt.Id));
However, this won't work if the attempt in question is not already stored in the database, and is just arbitrary data. For my uses now, this is good enough, but later I might still need to find a way to do this with completely arbitrary data.

You can't have an EF Core query which is partially server-side (the db.Attempt bit) and partially client-side (the newAttempt bit).
You need to first get the main list, then add to it.
var attempts = await db.Attempt.ToListAsync();
var results = attempts.Union([newAttempt]);

Although it seems much more straightforward to just use .Add or Append with one item.
var attempts = await db.Attempt.ToListAsync();
attempts.Add(newAttempt);

You possibly might want a hashset or dictionary instead (in order to de-duplicate against existing data), alternatively you might want to store the new data into the table first. It's not clear what you want.

Why is it partially server side and partially client side? Union returns IQueryable after all.. I just want it to be added to the query (to be used as the basis for other queries), does that mean I need to add said attempt to the database beforehand and then it'll work? or is there no way to union the query with an arbitrary attempt?

Wish I could select multiple responses as answers, as this and @Leszek Mazur's response really helped me understand what I was missing

Because the data in newAttempt is on the client only, bu the data coming from db is on the server. You can use Union, but you need to do it after doing the rest of the query.
